# "Did China Birth the Next Steve Jobs?"

Tags: word-usage

As the title of a Forbes [article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/benzingainsights/2012/12/07/did-china-birth-the-next-steve-jobs/), it has been drawn to my attention because of the use of *birth* as a verb. I think it should be *give birth to* or *bear*.

Comment: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/birth) would back up the author, although the usage is labeled as _rare_. Still, I can see why a headline writer would opt to use the verbal form – for headline writers, space is at a premium, and every omitted word has value.

Comment: See [The Give That Keeps On Gifting](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Birth* has been in use as a transitive verb since at least 1906 with the meaning ‘give birth to; to give rise to’. The OED describes it as ‘chiefly dialect and US dialect’. Speakers of AmEng may be able to tell us whether its use is more widespread, but it is not common in BrEng.

Comment: This usage is not common in the U.S., either, although I'm not startled to see it used this way, especially in a headline. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=births+a+child%2Cgives+birth+to+a+child%2Cbirth+an+idea&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows it's quite rare, particularly in the context of childbirth.

Comment: Yes, when it is used, it's probably used figuratively.

Comment: "Birthed a baby" or "birthed a babe" is certainly to be found, but I likewise agree that it's rare. I would have classified it as "poetic" (which for practical purposes pretty much means "know what it means when you see it, but don't actually use it").

Answer (score 3):

"Give rise to' would be a better phrase to use here. My guess is that a journalist/editor has thought 'birth' would grab people's attention and fill up the limited space they have for headlines.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that "Give Rise to" would be better than "Birth". _Give rise to_ implies something that happens over time, while _birth_ (as a verb) implies someone has sprung on the scene more suddenly. It all depends on which mood the headline writer was hoping to set.

Comment: They did succeed at least in grabbing my attention.

Comment: Did you mean _give rise to_ or _give birth to_? Why would  _give rise to_ be a better fit here?

Comment: "Give rise to' would be better wording because there's only one Steve Jobs in the world. "Give birth to' implies that it's a new thing/event. In the context of the original headline, it would be like creating another Steve Jobs in China.

Comment: +1: it helps journalists/editors etc. to be a bit informal in what they write if it can get more eyeballs